# Three.js 2D object collision with raycaster

Tags: three.js, 2d, collision

I'm trying to detect collision of two 2D object (for example, two THREE.CircleGeometry) on a plane.

My question: **is there a recommended method to detect 2D objet collision?** I have 2 attempts below but they are both bad. If anyone has experience on this before, would you please help? Thank you in advance.

**Here is my 1st attempt:**

```
//'player' is the Circle that I'm controlling. In the scene, there is another position-fixed circle, called 'target'.
// I hope to cast a ray from player to the target and detect collision.
// 'mouse' is a normalized direction THREE.Vector3()

raycaster.set(player.position, mouse);
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
for ( var i = 0; i < intersects.length; i++ ) {
    console.log("TEST");
    intersects[ i ].object.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
}
```

Obviously that didn't work. I already realized raycaster does not seem to work on 2D object. (I tested with 3D object, and it worked perfectly fine).

**Here comes the 2nd attempt:**

```
var dis = distance(target.position, player.position);
if (dis < 1) {
target.material.color.set(0xff0000);
}
```

This method **works** and I can detect collision between the two circles: player and target. **HOWEVER**, it leads to really **bad performance**, because it's absolutely non-necessary to check thousands of targets per render().

If anyone has any thoughts or any recommended reading, would you please advise? I tried to search online but most tutorial and examples are for 3D collision. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but maybe other person need.

I recommend the second methods thats you propos, but using a subset of the circles.

In a hypotetical map, you have 1000000 obstacles, of course, if you check the collision to every obstacle, you go to end few years later, but if you have a grid on the map, and place this circles in cells corresponding to the posicitions, the you can compare onlie the circles around the player, comparing onli the circles of the cells occuped for the player.

In thas ways is fast if you do a simple collision verification for this circles.